# html image tooltip problem

Tags: html, internationalization, spring-mvc

I have an image wherein i need to assign a tooltip depending on the language selected.... So the tooltip has to come from a resourse bundle relative to the locale/language.... I am using spring mvc framework... 
I am using the following code for image's title attribute....

title= < spring:message code="toolTipEnglish"/>

wherein toolTipEnglish corresponds to the a name-value pair in the properties file.. corresponding to each locale/language.... 
Problem is.... The tooltip is not taking the complete sentence but taking only the first work... iN short breaking at space... Eg:

toolTipEnglish=Change to English

The tooltip only shows "Change"

If i hardcode the tooltip as "Change to English".. 
it comes perfect....

But i wish to show the tooltip according to the language seletced.... 
Please help!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I've ever touched Spring, but presumably:

```
title="<spring:message code="toolTipEnglish"/>"
```

Since quote marks around attribute values are not optional if there are spaces in the value.